# jQuery.trim does not work when i try to filter a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox to put text in order to filter an html table. I want to trim the textbox contents before filter the table:

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/QFQ5k/94/

The line that makes the filtering is:

```
return $(this).find("[zip^='"+ $.trim($("#txtbox").val())+"']").length>0;
```

EDIT: It works succesfully, i tested it wrongly, but I **want that alone blank space shows all table rows.**

Comment: This works for me. what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The trim, does not trim the text. If you press backspace+text the blank space is not trimmed.

Comment: have you tried `$("#txtbox").val().trim()`?

Comment: @a_maar hey see the updated answer with updated fiddle link.

Comment: @Stephan trim() is a global function, cannot be used that way.

Comment: I meant the plain js, not the jquery one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filter only if there is something typed in the textbox, els i don't.

```
if($("#txtbox").val().length >0){
   // Filtering
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFQ5k/101/

now you can see the triming there. I just added some lines after the keyup event.

```
$("#txtbox").keyup(function () {
var a = $.trim($(this).val());
$(this).val(a);
```

***I hope this solves what you want to achieve.***

Comment: You can use space between the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Better use quicksearch for your requirement. I hope below sample helps you a bit.

[Quicksearch jquery plug-in](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid/Templates/CustomizedToolbar)